# save_model method in django admin barfs on update

Tags: python, django-admin

I'm using this snippet from the documentation:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()
```

I've used the admin site and successfully created entries in the model, but now when I try to edit the entry, clicking submit generates a TypeError:

```
 Database is trying to update a relational field of type CharField with a value of type User. Make sure you are setting the correct relations
```

I don't understand why it would throw this error now and not during the initial creation.

Is there a way around it?

ADDENDUM:

Reexamining the traceback for the error above, I also took at look at the local variables. It looks like there isn't any username information at all in the request variable, so I'm having my doubts that this works at all in the case of an update.

PS Since the traceback only shows a picture of the request object, the 'user' attribute is probably not displayed, but it could be there.

PPS: I found that the [documentation on the user attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) explains that [middleware must be activated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware), and when I check, I see that Heroku already added those settings for me. The attribute is indeed django.contrib.auth.models.User, whose username attribute is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please include the definition of the user field

Comment: @frmdstryr In my case, obj.user is just a username string.

Comment: you need to use a ForeignKey field instead,see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: @frmdstryr I cannot make sense of that considering I don't know for sure what table it would be pointing at. Do you mean the field should be hooked to usernames in auth_user? The username is supposed to be automatically populated from the request.

Comment: Basically I just want to know who last altered the record. I've seen in django admin that actions are reported... maybe I'm working too hard? Is that already tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that, whatever class `obj` belongs to, the user attribute of that class is not a foreign key to the User class that you are referring to, but just a CharField. Change the type of that attribute in the class that obj belongs to, migrate the database and then you will find this working.

If you just want it to be a string, not a foreign key relation, then use:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Any guess as to why it works correctly on creation (but fails on update?) Could it have to do with the 'change' argument?

Comment: @rschwieb: According to your update in the question, if there is no username info in the request parameter, that means the request is logged in. That MIGHT be a problem. But the entire problem can be seen only if you share more code...

Comment: I'm willing to share more, I'm just not sure what else is relevant. Beyond the admin for the class, the information I'm trying to get out of request, and the fact the attribute I'm trying to populate is a string, what else is there to day?

Comment: @rschwieb: The model of the obj's class will help

Comment: For all intents and purposes, obj is a subclass of models.Model with a field `user = models.CharField(max_length=25)` and a primary key id field. I want to be able to tell who last modified the entry.

Comment: After digging through it, I think your grey box is the solution I want. I'm still curious why it works on creation but not on updating though. Maybe it's just unintended shenanigans.